# Interior of a set int(A\int(A))

Tags: real-analysis, metric-spaces

Is int(A\int(A)) empty? This is obviously true when A is an open set but I was trying to think of a scenario with closed sets where it would fail to hold and I could not really think of an instance. For instance, int([0,1]) = (0,1). Then, int({0,1}) = $\emptyset$.

Comment: As a note on the linked dupe: While it is technically written in the context of $\mathbb{R}^n$ and metric spaces, if you copy angryavian's answer nearly verbatim, changing the one mention of "ball" to "subset," then you would have an answer that applies in general topological spaces.